# ArgumentOutOfRange on setting DataGrid DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

DataGrid I work with

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" AutoGeneratingColumn="datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

What I am trying to do - change DataContext from one DataTable to another (I am resetting it, because there can be removed columns). However when using

```
datagrid.DataContext = new_datatable;
```

As I do when I first set the table context - where it works just fine, I get ArgumentOutOfRange exception in mscorlib.dll because of argument index. The error gets raised even when nothing was changed in the datagrid/datatable. The table passed as new has the exact same columns and values, yet the exception is still raised.

Comment: you are setting `DataContext` instead of `ItemSource` and `DataTable` does not inherit IEnumerable

Comment: I am however doing the same step once before, and there it fills and autopopulates the grid correctly

Comment: can u post stacktrace? Look where the exception is throwing from. May be take a second look at `datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you set your DataContext from code-behind instead of using bindings?

Comment: It was my stupidity, forgot to switch off release and therefore didn't get stacktrace - the problem was indeed in Autogeneratingcolumn

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below DefaultView property of datatable.

```
datagrid.DataContext = new_datatable.DefaultView;
```

Comment: DataTable new_dt = (dataGrid.DataContext as DataTable).Copy();
    dataGrid.DataContext = new_dt.DefaultView;
    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

Still throws the same exception